# EditTexts dependentes em um GridView do Android

Tags: android, gridview, edittext

Tenho dois EditTexts, um de valor de desconto, outro de porcentagem e um ImageButton de atualizar, todos estão em um GridView.

Ao clicar no ImageButton, o valor digitado no campo de porcentagem deve ser convertido para Double e atribuído ao campo de valor. Da forma que eu fiz, não consigo pegar o valor digitado no campo de porcentagem.

Segue o trecho de código:

```
@SuppressLint({ "InflateParams", "UseValueOf" })
public View getView(  final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    holder = null;
     if (convertView == null|| convertView.getTag()== null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_itens_pedido, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();


        holder.etValorDesc.setTag(new Integer(position));
        holder.etDescontoSaida.setTag(new Integer(position));
        holder.imgAtualizar.setTag(new Integer(position));


        holder.etDescontoSaida.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

               values[position].Desconto= Double.parseDouble(s.toString())/100;

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                int count, int after) {


            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                int before, int count) {

            }

        });


        holder.imgAtualizar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Integer position = (Integer)v.getTag();
                holder.etValorDesc.setText(String.valueOf(values[position].Desconto));


                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Trocando para

```
if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_itens_pedido, parent, false);

    holder = new ViewHolder();

.... resto do código aqui ...

convertView.setTag(holder);

} else {
   holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
```

não funciona?

Comment: O valor convertido está sendo convertido e atribuído para a classe, porém, ainda não consigo recuperar este valor e atribuir ao campo de valor do desconto.

Comment: Não faltou também :
holder.etValorDesc = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nome_do_campo);

Comment: Não, já havia iniciado este componente.